# How to receive a value of a variable declared inside an "await"ed method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, filereader, domparser

I am trying to convert an uploaded file into a string using DOMParser. To do this, i am using two methods as follows:

**method to upload a file**

```
handleFileInput(event){
    setTimeout(async ()=>{
      if(event.target.files.item(0)!=null){
        this.uploadedFile=event.target.files.item(0);
        this.XMLAsString= await this.convertFileToString(this.uploadedFile); 
        console.log("XML as String-> ",this.XMLAsString); 
      }
    }, 3500);
  }
```

**method to convert a file to string**

```
convertFileToString(file):String{
    let fileInString:String=null;
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event) =>{
      fileInString=fileReader.result as String
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
    //console.log("XML as String inside convert method-> ",this.XMLAsString);
    if(fileInString!=null){
      return fileInString
    }
  }
```

But when i try print the value of `XMLAsString` in `handleFileInput(event)` (in line 6) function, it returns undefined. I understand this is happening due to the `fileReader.onload` but now, how do i fetch the value of `fileInString` in `XMLAsString`?

**NOTE:** I need to keep the `setTimeOut` as it is, as i need it to do some other tasks.

Comment: async/await is syntax sugar for Promises ... convertFileToString does not return a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX i have used async await at some other place as well, the function there doesn't return a promise either. But it works fine.....

Comment: no you haven't. sure, you can await anything, but the only asynchronous value you can await is a promise